# AAD B2C: Returning value: [] when trying to filter by identities

Tags: azure, api, microsoft-graph-api, identity

I'm using Microsoft AAD B2C with User Flow.

I have a user that returns those identities objects:

```
        "identities": [
            {
                "signInType": "phoneNumber",
                "issuer": "ourtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "issuerAssignedId": "+55444444444"
            },
            {
                "signInType": "userPrincipalName",
                "issuer": "ourtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "issuerAssignedId": "ausdhasuduasd@ourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        ],
```

I'm trying to filter by:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?$filter=(identities/any(i:i/issuer eq 'ourtenant.onmicrosoft.com' and i/issuerAssignedId eq '55444444444'))
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,identities&$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '+55444444444' and c/issuer eq 'ourtenant.onmicrosoft.com')
```

But it returns only:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users",
    "value": []
}
```

I also tried to swap i for c, x, the filter order, without select, but it doesn't work, only returns value: [].

The tenant is correct, and the user's number is correct.
I tried to use beta and also v1.0. Tried to filter with "startsWith"  on phoneNumber, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: It's actually Microsoft Graph, but I need at least 1500 rep to add the word "Microsoft" in the tag.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I fetched the identities of the user:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserId/identities
```

[image]

When I tried to filter the identities, ***I faced the same issue as below***:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,id&$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq 'xxx' and c/issuer eq 'xxx')
```

[image]

The issue usually occurs if you are passing wrong values while calling the API.

- Try adding `+` while passing the phone number like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?$filter=(identities/any(i:i/issuer eq 'ourtenant.onmicrosoft.com' and i/issuerAssignedId eq '+55444444444'))
```

- If still the issue persists, try fetching another user and check if the user account has sufficient privileges to perform the action.

I am able to execute the query successfully like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,Identities&$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq 'xxx' and c/issuer eq 'xxx')
```

[image]

**References:**

[List users - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-get-a-user-account-using-a-sign-in-name)

[User query $filter ignores identities/issuer - MS Graph API and Azure B2C by Andrew Campbell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/826199/user-query-filter-ignores-identities-issuer-ms-gra)